# PHP: Get RSA public key from private key string/file

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication, openssl

I'm building a basic encrypted chat application with laravel. Im trying to authenticate a user given a private key that was generated when the user signed up.

The users' public key is stored in the DB. When the user wants to log in, the need to upload the private key that was given to them. I want to compare the public key in the DB and the public key from the original private key.

```
/**
 * Validate user key file for login
 */
public function validateKey($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    if (!($value instanceof UploadedFile)) return false;

    // Get user to match key
    $user = $this->data['username'];

    // Get public key from file
    $privateKey = File::get($value->getRealPath());

    dd($privateKey);
}
```

I am able to get the private key in a string format. From here I cannot seem to generate or extract the public key to compare to the DB value.

Comment: you only need to let the users upload their public keys and share them, that way they can send encrypted messages to each other which they decrypt with their private key.... the private key is  SECRET never share with anyone or upload anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should also never upload their private key to your server.  You should never have your private key at a remote location.

The point of having two keys is one key can decrypt any message encrypted by the other key.   The major difference between the public key and the private key in most algorithms would be more or less which one you keep private and which one you share.  In RSA, the private key is designated, but you still do not want to upload it or share it.

---

Redacted: ~That's not how public/private keys work.  You can't extract one from the other.  If you could, that would defeat the purpose of the asymmetric encryption.~

As @iainn pointed out, you can extract a public key from an RSA private key, however I still do not recommend having users upload their private key.

Comment: i was also wondering if he stores the key in ascii armored format or byte wise

Comment: @Devon Thanks for your answer. I'm very new to encryption and cryptography. Do you have any architecture suggestions on how I should be using the keys to authenticate or just decrypt messages in general?

Comment: @MoussaHarajli users need to share their public keys only, that way they should be able to send encrypted messages to each other

Comment: @MoussaHarajli, in general, most authentication works by "signing" a message.  This would be encrypting a message with your private key, sending it, and then the server attempts to decrypt it with the public key and verify the messages matches what it expects.

Comment: You can absolutely extract a public key from a private key - that's what `ssh-keygen -y` does. Private and public keys are dramatically different, they're not just two halves of a whole where you choose which one you want to keep secret.

Comment: @iainn that is what I thought as well. At this point, I'm trying to figure out the best way to keep the keys safe as well as being able to correctly authenticate and decrypt messages. Whether it be on the client side or server side.

Comment: @iainn, It seems you're right.  I didn't think it was possible to extract one from the other with asymmetric,  but perhaps RSA works differently than other algorithms.